# Prolog - filter a list with a list as condition

Tags: prolog

I have the following facts:

```
breads([italian_wheat, hearty_italian, honey_oat, parmesan_oregano, multigrain, flatbread]).
sauces([chipotle_southwest, ranch, bbq, chili_sauce, tomato_sauce, mayonnaise, mustard_sauce]).
unhealthy_breads([hearty_italian, honey_oat, parmesan_oregano, flatbread]).
unhealthy_sauces([mayonnaise, chipotle_southwest, ranch]).
```

Now I would like to filter out breads and sauces by the lists of unhealthy breads & unhealthy sauces. I would like to create a "function" that works similiar to this:

```
filter(breads,unhealthy_breads,Healthy).
```

that gives the output:

```
Healthy = [italian_wheat, multigrain]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that :

```
breads([italian_wheat, hearty_italian, honey_oat, parmesan_oregano, multigrain, flatbread]).
sauces([chipotle_southwest, ranch, bbq, chili_sauce, tomato_sauce, mayonnaise, mustard_sauce]).
unhealthy_breads([hearty_italian, honey_oat, parmesan_oregano, flatbread]).
unhealthy_sauces([mayonnaise, chipotle_southwest, ranch]).

test(Bad, X) :-
    member(X, Bad).

filter(Data, Bad, Output) :-
   call(Data, Input_1),
   call(Bad, Input_2),

   % Filter elements for which Goal fails. 
   % True if List2 contains those elements Xi of List1 for which call(Goal, Xi) fails.
   exclude(test(Input_2),Input_1, Output).
```

Example

```
?- filter(breads,unhealthy_breads,Healthy).
Healthy = [italian_wheat, multigrain].
```